# How to implement Geography or geometry with spatial index implementation to find entities in the bounding box?

Tags: sql, sql-server, geospatial-pdf, geography-data-type, geometry-data-type

I have entities saved in SQL table with Lat and long values. I added another column to store Geometry values.

**Code for updating Geometry column**
UPDATE [dbo].[table]
SET [GeoLocation] = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(' + CAST([Longitude] AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + 
                    CAST([Latitude] AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')', 4326)

Now i need to modify my current procedure which work on Longitude & Latitude columns to newly added Geometry column.
The stored procedure basically takes input as @Minlat, @MaxLat, @MinLong & @MaxLong and returns the entities between these coordinates.These points are then displayed on UI

**Current Procedure filter**
select Entity, *
from Table
WHERE Latitude BETWEEN @Min_lat AND @Max_Lat 
AND Longitude BETWEEN @Min_long AND @Max_Long

I need use the Geometry column in the above where condition so that it returns the same result.

I have created a polygon with the 4 inputs and used STIntersects function however it is not giving me any result. Not sure i should be using Geometry or geography time.
The entities i show on map are static.

**Code to create bounding box **
DECLARE @boundingRect Geometry
SET @boundingRect = 'POLYGON((' + @minX + ' ' + @minY + ', ' + 
                                  @maxX + ' ' + @minY + ', ' + 
                                  @maxX + ' ' + @maxY + ', ' + 
                                  @minX + ' ' + @maxY + ', ' + 
                                  @minX + ' ' + @minY + '))'
**New Procedure filter**
select Entity, *
from Table
WHERE GeoLocation.STWithin(@boundingRect) = 1

If i compare data for the select statments it is different. the STWithin does not select any records from table

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user please take the [Tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour). Please **edit** your question to contain a question. It is more likely to be answered if you *try*  to implement the technology before asking.

Comment: What have you tried?  The lack of a question mark makes it difficult to discern a question.

Comment: I have created the polygon using geometry::STGeomFromText from the min and max of lat log values and used the STIntersects function in where condition and it did not return any result, however when i query the same on lat and long values it returns me output. How to create a bounding box from lat long input values and compare them with a geometry filed to return only those entities in the bounding box??

Comment: Please **edit the question** in response to requests for clarification. Since the most likely cause is your point encoding,  you should also include the code you used to transfer the coordinates to geometry. 80% of the time, a well-researched question will answer itself.